# How to dismiss a React Modal using createPortal()?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

Trying to dismiss a Modal dialog from within the Modal. I'm using ReactDOM.createPortal().

index.html

```
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="modal"></div>
  </body>
```

ResponseModal.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

// The gray background
const backdropStyle = {
...
};

// The modal "window"
const modalStyle = {
...
};

const MODAL_ROOT = document.querySelector("#modal");

const JSX_MODAL = ({ children, setShowResponses }) => (
  <div style={backdropStyle}>
    <div style={modalStyle}>
      Child: {children}
      <br />
      <input
        type="button"
        value="Dismiss"
        onClick={() => {
          setShowResponses(false);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
);

function Modal({ showResponses, ...props }) {
  console.log("floop", showResponses);
  if (showResponses) {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(JSX_MODAL(props), MODAL_ROOT);
  }
  return null;
}

export default Modal;
```

And finally, the containing component:

```
const LargeCell = ({ SCID, extra, fen, color }) => {
  const [showResponses, setShowResponses] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
         ...
      }}
      onClick={() => setShowResponses(true)}
    >
      <SmallCell {...{ SCID, color }} />
      <DiagramForCell {...{ fen }} padding="3em"></DiagramForCell>
      <span className="diff-text opening-text">{extra.opening.desc}</span>
      <ResponsesModal {...{ showResponses, setShowResponses }}>
        FLUM!
      </ResponsesModal>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When I click on the LargeCell div, I see:
[image: The Modal]

However, the dismiss button doesn't work. I'm sure that setShowResponses(false) is called, but there is no re-rendering of the Modal, so it is not dismissed. If I look at the Modal component in Chrome devtools, the state of showResponses still shows **true**.

So the question is: what is the correct way to dismiss this Modal?

Answer (score 0):

So LargeCell was a table cell component, of which there were multiple. What I did was to push the Modal to the table level, and show/hide it from there:

```
        {showResponses ? (
          <ResponsesModal {...{ setShowResponses }}>FLUM!</ResponsesModal>
        ) : null}
```

setShowResponses is called by the Dismiss button in the Modal as shown previously.

The disadvantage is that to bring up the modal, each LargeCell needs setShowResponses, also.  That prop has to be pushed several levels down. That's okay for now, but I'm starting to wonder if I should use a context.